# Where can I find windows crash dump (Blue screen crash dump)?

Tags: windows, winapi

Where can I find blue screen of death crash dump?

Answer (score 23):

Your crash dump location will depend on what is set in the system.

To find out where it is located go to your control panel, then system, then advanced system settings (in Windows 7) or the advanced tab (in Windows XP), click the startup and recovery 'settings' button.

Near the bottom of the startup and recovery settings window will be a dump file location text box which will specify where you can find it.

More info about dump files can be found here -> http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-crash-dump-files.aspx

Comment: +1. Teach a man to fish... I've removed my incomplete answer.

Comment: Note that if you don't have enough disk space then the memory dump is discarded without any attempt to save a smaller dump.